# What is the conventional name for a method accepting a closure and providing temporal field access for it?

Tags: rust, naming-conventions, naming, conventions

I have a Rust struct which can be simplified like this:

```rust
struct Struct {
    field: String // the type doesn't matter
}
impl Struct {
    pub fn method<F, R>(&self, closure: F) -> R
    where
        F: FnOnce(&String) -> R
    {
        closure(&self.field)
    }
}
```

Are there any conventional names for `Struct::method` (used in the Rust Book or the standard library in similar cases)? Is it expected to be `apply`, `visit`..?

Comment: There is none. This depends on your domain.

Comment: @Shepmaster do you mean `std` doesn't have even one occurrence of this pattern?

Comment: I can't think of one with 30 seconds of effort. Even if there was, that doesn't mean that there would be a naming pattern you could use / extend.

Comment: Does [`Option::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map) meet your criteria? [`Option::filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.filter)?

Comment: If there is only one such method and the data it receives is central to `Struct`, I'd go with `map()` (as in `Option`) or `with()` (as in [`LocalKey`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.LocalKey.html)). If there can be multiple such methods, or it's not obvious which field it receives, I'd go call it the more explicit `with_field`.

Comment: @user4815162342 'with' seems like a good match, thank you. Would you like to post it as an answer?

Comment: @Shepmaster `filter` is just `T -> T` but `map` seems nice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is only one such method and the data it receives is central to `Struct`, I'd go with:

- `map()` if it consumes/transforms `Struct` and returns a new `Struct`, as in [`Option::map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map)
- `with()` if it receives a shared reference to the data, as in [`LocalKey::with()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.LocalKey.html#method.with)
- `with_mut()` if the function receives a unique/mutable reference to the data. (I don't have a good reference for this one, but it's a logical extension of `with()`, and consistent with `iter()` and `iter_mut()` on containers.)

If there are multiple such methods, or it's not obvious what subset of `Struct`'s data it operates on, I'd call add the field name, as in `with_field()` or `with_mut_field()`.

Comment: The unstable [`std::ffi::VaListImpl::with_copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.VaListImpl.html#method.with_copy) provides weak support for the `with_field` naming. Of course, if the method has some behavior besides simply calling the closure, it should probably be named something more specific (like `Vec::resize_with`, `Option::get_or_insert_with`, etc.)